# reading first 5 fields of csv file in php

Tags: php

I am confused on how to read a csv file in php ( only the first 4 fields) and exclude the remaining fileds.

```
Sno,Name,Ph,Add,PO
1,Bob,0102,Suit22,89
2,Pop,2343,Room2,78
```

I just want to read first 3 fileds and jump to next data. cannot figure out how to do through fgetcsv

any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a comment to the sample fgetcsv code for you:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        // iterate over each column here
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            // handle column data here
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            // exit the loop after 3rd column parsed
            if ($c == 2) break;
        }
        ++$row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: if i need to insert this data into mysql , can you tell me where to insert the statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without the `fgetcsv` function:

```
$lines = file('data.csv');
$linecount = count($lines);
for ($i = 1; $i < $linecount; $i++){
   $fields = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
   $sno  = $fields[0];
   $name = $fields[1];
   $ph   = $fields[2];
   $add  = $fields[3];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this assumes that the file is correct (there are no lines with fewer than 4 fields). I know that NOTICE level error is not so important, but anyway. Especially when you debug, it's best to get rid of notices.

I suggest adding if(count($fields) < 4) //Error handle// for a row

Comment: I was just showing the concept. There's no need to convolute a demonstration with nitty-gritty bulletproofing. He asked for four fields, so I gave him four fields.